# Python hanging backwards triangle with stars

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a hanging triangle backwards with stars.
The following code works for the normal one:

```
F = "*"
E = 16
while E > 1:
    E -= 1
    print(E * "*")
```

and it displays:

```
***************
**************
*************
************
***********
**********
*********
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

I need to make this backwards with the while function like:

```
***************
 **************
  *************
   ************
    ***********
     **********
      *********
       ********
        *******
         ******
          *****
           ****
            ***
             **
              *
```

I can do it with a for function but I am stuck with the while:

```
E = 15
for x in range (E,0,-1):
    print((E-x) * ' ' + x * '*')
```

I don't specifically want you to tell me the answer and I'll copy it.
If you can tell me how I can add spaces to the line to begin with and the end to be in a straigth column, I'll greatly appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution.
As a person explained it to me on Reddit, you have to keep count of the spaces in front of the stars.
It begins with zero for the first line, and then it's one, and then two until it's 15.
G is the spaces in front.

```
F = "*"
E = 16
G = 0
while E > 1:
    E -= 1
    print(G * ' ', E * "*")
    G += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner using [`str.rjust`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust)

```
char = '*'
size = 16
[print((i*char).rjust(size)) for i in reversed(range(size))]
```